# Trap clicks on links inside jQuery-UI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm having some problems with Jquery Dialog Box and links inside. I want to open a dialog which loads a child template with a list of objects. What Im trying to do next is making links of this objects and when you click them they load in the same dialog. How should i do this? Can i mark the links with an ID and somehow start a function on a click? Or whats the best way?

```
$("#mylist").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#dialog').load($(this).attr('href')).dialog({
      width: 800,
      height: 530,
      resizable: false,
      title: "Dialog Title",
      autoOpen: true,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a delegate event handler on the dialog div that traps clicks on links:

```
$("#dialog").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dialog").load($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Comment: OK! Thanks! Should this go in under the same function? and what does "a" represent here? Sorry im very new to jquery

Comment: It can go anywhere if wrapped inside `$(function(){})` construct.

Comment: Great! And the "a" is it a part of the eventhandler or just somthing you wrote for an example?

Comment: `a` is a selector matching `<a>` tags. Just about any selector can be used (e.g. `a[rel=dialog]`, `input[type=submit]` etc).